# How do i make a button save data to another page without linking to it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Whenever I in put details to a questionnaire I made, I press the button to confirm details but this links me to the page I want it saved to. I don't want this to happen as I need to complete more things down the page that are in different form controls.
So what I want is a button that saves the text box answer to the other page without linking it.

```
    <form action="Assignmentcheckout.php" method="post">
<p>Surname:<input name="surname" type="text" required="required">
<br>
<br>
Name:<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<br>
<br>
Street:<input type="text" name="street">
<br>
<br>
Suburb:<input type="text" name="suburb">
<br>
<br>
City:<input type="text" name="city">
<br>
<br>
State:<select name="state">
    <option>QLD</option>
    <option>NSW</option>
    <option>VIC</option>
    <option>TAS</option>
    <option>WA</option>
    <option>SA</option>
    <option>NT</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="delivery">Delivery
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="pickup">Pickup<br>
<br>
</p>
<button type="submit" value="Confirm details">Confirm details</button>
</form>
```

Please provide an answer

Comment: im only familiar in php or html but I can learn jscript if nessecary

Comment: I just need a button at the bottom of the code that doesn't transfer me to the page, but saves information to it.

Comment: so later on I can go to the page and see the information previously entered

Answer (score 0):

Ajax would transfer the information without refreshing the exiting page. If you are looking to keep data available for further inputs, you might want to look into using $_SESSION